# Is there a minimal way of converting an associative array to a numeric array with each item storing the key and value?

Tags: php, associative-array

I simply need to convert, in PHP:

```
[
    'id' => '1',
    'code' => 'DRX',
    'company_name' => 'Dave Ricks Ltd'
], 
[
    'id' => '2',
    'code' => 'LRT',
    'company_name' => 'LiveRave Ltd'
]
```

To...

```
[
    [
        [
            'name' => 'id',
            'value' => '1',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'code',
            'value' => 'DRX',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'company_name',
            'value' => 'Dave Ricks Ltd',
        ]
    ], 
    [
        [
            'name' => 'id',
            'value' => '2',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'code',
            'value' => 'LRT',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'company_name',
            'value' => 'LiveRave Ltd',
        ]
    ]
]
```

I know I can do this with a couple of foreach loops but wondered if using some of PHPs array functions I could do the same with less lines of code?

Comment: array_walk() with a callback using array_combine() with array_keys() and array_values() might work

Comment: why dont you use JSON? http://json-schema.org/examples.html Then you can use json_encode and json_decode http://php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your initial array is actually

```
[
  [
    'id' => '1', 'code' => 'DRX', 'company_name' => 'Dave Ricks Ltd'
  ],
  [
    'id' => '2', 'code' => 'LRT', 'company_name' => 'LiveRave Ltd'
  ]
]
```

since that's the kind of thing you'd get from a database. If I'm wrong and you've posted the actual var_dump/print_r of the array, that's very strange, but we can add a step to reorganize it.

So all we need to do is

```
$input = [
    [
        'id' => '1',
        'code' => 'DRX',
        'company_name' => 'Dave Ricks Ltd',
    ], 
    [
        'id' => '2',
        'code' => 'LRT',
        'company_name' => 'LiveRave Ltd',
    ]
];

$output = array_map(function($elem) { 

    return [
        ['name' => 'id', 'value' => $elem['id'] ],
        ['name' => 'code', 'value' => $elem['code'] ],
        ['name' => 'company_name', 'value' => $elem['company_name'] ],
    ];

}, $input);
print_r($output);
```

If you want the conversion more generic:

```
$output = array_map(function($elem) { 

    $result = [];
    foreach ($elem as $key => $value) {
        $result[] = ['name' => $key, 'value' => $value];
    }
    return $result;

}, $input);
print_r($output);
```

I'm thinking about whether there's an way to remove that inner foreach - but I don't think there is one that's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
while ($array) {
    $item = array_shift($array);

    $new_entry = array();

    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $new_item['name'] = $key;
        $new_item['value'] = $value;

        $new_entry[] = $new_item;
    }

    $new_array[] = $new_entry;
}

$final_array = array($new_array);

print_r($final_array);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => id
                            [value] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => code
                            [value] => DRX
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => company_name
                            [value] => Dave Ricks Ltd
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => id
                            [value] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => code
                            [value] => LRT
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => company_name
                            [value] => LiveRave Ltd
                        )

                )

        )

)
```